# Toggle specific element when css class is used multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have developed my own dropdown module, which works fine so far. However, I have the problem that dropdowns that have the same trigger class open when clicked. How can I focus only on the element that was clicked. I also tried to focus the element using `$(this).find`, but unfortunately this does not work for me. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger-dropdown').on('click', function(){
        $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').toggleClass('filter-dropdown-active');
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).click(function(){
    if($('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').hasClass('filter-dropdown-active')) {
        $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').toggleClass('filter-dropdown-active');
    }
});

$('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

/* Triggers Checkbox Icon for Dropdowns */

$(".dropdown-items").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.checkbox').toggleClass("checkbox-selected");
  });
```

```css
.sidebar-filter-wrapper{
    padding-top:1.25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.filter-dropdown{
    position: relative;
}

.filter-label{
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color ease 250ms;
}

.filter-label:hover{
    background-color: rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.20);
    color: #303030;
}

.filter-label img{
    margin-left: .625rem;
}

.filter-dropdown-wrapper{
    margin-top:.625rem;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5rem,;
    left: 0;
}

.filter-dropdown-active{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-items{
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-items:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.checkbox{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 0.625rem;
}

.checkbox-selected{
    background-color: #BC9590;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-color: #bc9590;
    background-image: url(../img/checked.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
            <div class="sidebar-filter-wrapper">
                <div class="filter-pill-wrapper">
                    <div class="filter-dropdown">
                        <a class="filter-label trigger-dropdown">
                            Marken vor Ort
                            <img src="img/toggle.svg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Skinceuticals</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Babor</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Eucerin</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Hermés</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Kérastase</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Clinique</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
       <div class="filter-pill-wrapper">
                    <div class="filter-dropdown">
                        <a class="filter-label trigger-dropdown">
                            Marken vor Ort
                            <img src="img/toggle.svg">
                        </a>
                        <div class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Skinceuticals</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Babor</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Eucerin</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Hermés</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Kérastase</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
                                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                                <p>Clinique</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle the class for the wrapper in the same parent element because the class selector select all the elements with the same class in the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.trigger-dropdown').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').toggleClass('filter-dropdown-active');
    return false;
  });
});
```